# Removing one letter in an SQL table column name breaks my PHP page. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database that is hosted professionally. It has been running without issue for over a year. No updates or changes have been made to software that I am aware.

In my PHP page I have a test query string

When I run this, I receive the following error messages:

> mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away
>
> mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header

Has anyone seen this issue before? To be honest I did check, double check, and then triple check my code but I have missed things before and won't count out the fact that the issue could very likely be blatantly obvious to someone who hasn't been nose deep in the project as I have. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

The MySQL version is 5.6.43

I was able to trace the issue back to what seems like the name of the table column "character_zone". Strange as it is, when I change the name of the column to "character_zonea" and update my PHP accordingly it works flawlessly. The $con variable wasn't changed and works with other code in my project. No paths have been altered and the sql limits haven't been tampered with.

```sql
$query = "SELECT * FROM app_characters WHERE character_zone = 'ZZZZZZZ'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

I see these errors until I change the name of character_zone column to character_zonea in my database and update PHP accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried calling the column for example `character_zona` or any other names?

Comment: @Dharman I fully agree. This is only a test on a local machine. It's just connecting to an outside database. The code in question is not yet live. I will try dropping the E entirely from the word and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Dharman I changed the column name a few times to test. It seems like the 4'th letter in the word "zone" causes it to break. This is a very strange glitch. I just changed the column name to inlude "_id" after zone and it's working fine now. I'll just leave it like that because I have no idea what could be causing this issue. I'll try to make a report of it officially.

Comment: FYI I can't reproduce it on MariaDB 10.3.7 if that means anything to you.

Comment: What happens if you escape `character_zone` with backtics?

Comment: @Jerry I'm not sure. I haven't tried that. I'm heading out for a while but when I get back in I'll try that and see what difference it makes. I know that it is working now but only since I've added the "_id" at the end.